# Swift Firestore Data Mapping returns nil

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to fetch user data from Firestore but it returns nil, which point am i missing?
Here is my model;

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserModel: Codable {

var userId: String
var userName: String
var userNameLowercased: String
var email: String
var profileImageUrl: String
var friend_requests: [Friends]


enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    
    case userId = "id"
    case userName
    case userNameLowercased = "username_lowercased"
    case email
    case profileImageUrl = "profile image"
    case friend_requests
   }
}

struct Friends: Codable, Hashable {
    var userid: String
}
```

It is OK when manuel mapping all fields but I don't want to do this manually and trying to learn Codable issue. Service function is below:

```
func fetchUserProfile(userId: String, completion: (_ userM: UserModel) -> ()) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("users_profile").whereField("id", isEqualTo: userId).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        } else {
            
            if querySnapshot?.isEmpty != true {
                
                let userM = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { document -> UserModel? in
                    return try? document.data(as: UserModel.self)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `try?` use `do { try ... } catch { print(error) }` and print the actual error.

Comment: Nobody can tell when you don't even explain what your dataset contains.

Comment: Did you mean Firestore data?

Comment: Your structure should have `@DocumentID` and the issue could simply be that userId was not found. Also, - *but it returns nil* - we don't know what *it* is - the firebase call? The querySnapshot? userId? But. Before doing anything else, please read the guide on using Codable with Firestore. It will get you going the right direction and save you a lot of time. [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) from @peterfriese

Comment: Problem solved. It was about coding keys, I made a typo :( and resolve fetching problem. By the way I read peterfriese’s guide, i  have got the data without DocumentId, it is not necessary, but thanks for the help guys!

Comment: The comment about `Your structure should have @DocumentID` was because DocumentId's are unique identifiers and typically in a users collection you'd use the users uid as the documentId and it gives a place for Firebase to map the uid to. It then eliminates the need to ALSO store the uid as a field, simplifying the structure.